# CreateFile API with empty lpFileName

Tags: windows, file, winapi

I have just discovered that it is possible to set the parameter `lpFileName` to `null` in `CreateFile` and still returns a valid handle.

Is the returned handle valid and able to read/write? If so, where are the bytes stored?

Comment: The MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx - doesn't say anything about what happens when `lpFileName` is null.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that it's the same as piping output to `/dev/null` on *nix. It's a valid thing to do, but the output goes nowhere. Have you tried writing to and then reading from the "file" using the handle and seeing what happens?

Comment: @ChrisF I haven't tried it yet but I will as soon as I get to it.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what procmon shows as the call stack for a null filename.

Comment: What version of Windows? Could you please show your call to ::CreateFile()?

Answer (score 3):

Please show your code. I just tested on Windows 7 x64:

```
auto h = CreateFile(nullptr, GENERIC_ALL, 0, nullptr, 0, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
auto err = GetLastError();
ASSERT(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
VERIFY(CloseHandle(h));
```

The compiler warns:

> x.cpp(148): warning C6387: '*Param*(1)' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'CreateFileW'.

And when running the program the `ASSERT` fails and err is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Maybe you compared to `NULL`, not to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`?